# PostgreSQL directory doesn't appear where database says it is

Tags: postgresql, macos-catalina

I am newbie in postgres. I am trying  change the access type to my local database. I read many blogs about how to do this but when I tried locate the PostgresQL folder, it doesn't appear in any place. I entered to database and write `SHOW hba_file` then I got the folder path. But, when I am looking for it from bash, the folder doesn't exist. I am not sure what is happening here. I am on Mac Catalina 10.15.6. I am using Iterm2 with ZSH.

[image: This is the path that postgres show me]

[image: This is the content of Library folder]

Comment: Your screenshot suggests that you executed the `ls -a` in `~/Library`, not in `/Library`

Comment: What is the difference? Library is the folder which is nested in root home, isn't? @Bergi

Comment: I'm not a mac expert, but I don't think the root directory is the same as the home directory.

Comment: Each user (including root) has a ~/Library directory.  There is a separate /Library directory.

Comment: yes @korry, you are correct. I just learned it. Thanks!. If one want to see Library root directory, one should use sudo cd ~/...